# Duplicate deletion (same time) in question timeline

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, spam, timeline

Impressed by how quickly a post on Academia SE was correctly flagged as spam, I looked at [the timeline for Academia post 142860](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/142860/timeline) (10k on Academia required) — it was deleted 58 seconds after posting, very good:

[image: screenshot of timeline for post 142860 on academia]

The screenshot shows that the question was asked 2020-01-14 11:34:36Z, and got deleted and locked by Community♦ at 2020-01-14 11:35:34Z... **twice**.

How did it get locked and deleted twice?  Did it get twelve rather than the required six spam flags, or is there some other reason?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was caused by a race condition. Two users happened to cast a sixth spam flag on the post at *exactly* the same time, which caused the system to process all the resulting actions twice for the post because neither process knew anything about the other process already running.

Comment: I wonder if it requires undeleting twice (?)